# How to register a BroadcastReceiver() inside a thread

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a soundrecorder android thread and i need to know if mic/headset is connected or not while recording,so i need to use a BroadcastReceiver() inside the thread.how can i register that? this.registerReceiver() wont work because it only works inside activities.

If using broadcasereceivers inside a thread is not a good idea,so whats the solution?

here is the code which would work inside an activity and wont work inside a thread:

```
    headsetReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.i("Broadcast Receiver", action);
            if ((action.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) == 0) // if
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // action
                                                                        // match
                                                                        // a
                                                                        // headset
                                                                        // one
            {
                int headSetState = intent.getIntExtra("state", 0); // get
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // headset
                                                                    // state
                                                                    // property
                int hasMicrophone = intent.getIntExtra("microphone", 0);// get
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // headset
                                                                        // microphone
                                                                        // property
                if ((headSetState == 0) && (hasMicrophone == 0)) // headset
                                                                    // was
                                                                    // unplugged
                                                                    // &
                                                                    // has
                                                                    // no
                                                                    // microphone
                {
                    // do whatever
                }
            }
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass the context to the Thread constructor and then use it to register the broadcast receiver:

```
//this.ctx is passed to the Thread constructor
this.ctx.registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
```

Do not forget to unregister your receiver in finally{} in your Thread or leaks may occur:

```
finally{
       ctx.unregisterReceiver(headsetReceiver);
}
```

In order to change UI inside main thread(eg an activity), you will need to setup a handler