# LocalBroadcastReceiver doesn't work from inside a thread

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager

I am building a simple chat application. When I receive a message, I sent a broadcast message.

As this is run inside a thread started by a service, I pass the context to the thread. `MyConnection` is a class extending thread.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();       
    connection = new MyConnection(getApplicationContext());
}
```

So inside the thread when I receive a message, I do this...

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("from", message.getFrom());
i.putExtra("message", message.getBody());
i.setAction(MyService.MESSAGE_RECEIVED);                
_context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

`_context` is the `getApplicationContext()` I passed to the constructor of the thread. I have the `receiver` registered in my Manifest file.

So this is all working and my receiver receives the message successfully.

Now I want to change this to use the `LocalBroadcastManager`. So what I did was simply change the `_context.sendBroadcast(i)` to

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(_context).sendBroadcast(i);
```

However my `BroadcastReceiver` is not receiving any of the broadcasts sent this way.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to register the receiver in a different way in Manifest to receive local broadcasts? Are there any other steps required to make it work?

Comment: can you try this way ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12270926/1218762 , i'm not sure about this

Comment: this is working for me :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16832647/1218762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register your broadcast receiver with `registerReceiver` or in manifest?

Instead of passing `getApplicationContext()` pass `this`, because `Service` extends `Context`, too.

Comment: So it doesn't matter which context I pass? I thought I have to use the same context for both sending and receiving. That is why I used the `getApplicationContext`.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter as long as you pass the same intent for broadcast. Indeed, one application can send a broadcast and another one receive it, contexts are then obviously different.